# @DbRef is not saving child object automatically in spring data mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, dbref

I am currently using GA release of Spring Data MongoDB framework and @DbRef is not saving child object automatically in spring data mongodb. Can you tell me how can i make it work?

Answer (score 9):

Saving child objects is not built into Spring Data MongoDB so you have to do it manually or you can extend [AbstractMongoEventListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/event/AbstractMongoEventListener.html) as I described it in my article: [Spring Data MongoDB cascade save on DBRef objects](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/11/spring-data-mongodb-cascade-save-on-dbref-objects.html)

Comment: Can you tell why the ObjectId is mandatory? because I am doing Id implementation with long

Comment: hey @Maciej can you please update the link to your article? moreover, I wanted a way to do it for db referenced collection object, do we have a way. I tried extending AbstractMongoEventListener, but my test case while saving and updating fails.